# exceptional error : attributeCode "thumbnail" does not exist in magento2

Tags: magento2

Hi guys can anyone exlain why i am getting this error in magento2 fronend , all commands runs succesfully i have installed amasty extension of layered navigation ,it works fine in dashboard but on frontend there is some attribute missing , any expert can save my time please ???

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Attribute with
>   attributeCode "thumbnail" does not exist.

[image]

edit : --------------
i solved it my own , i goto my phpadmin

```
(`SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute)
```

run this query , and change the attribute_id of thumbnail from 0 to 1 and it works fine now.